# Multiple Complex types in parameters of Web API call

Tags: parameters, asp.net-web-api2

I am doing a POC and seeing if I can't convert one of our old .asmx webservices into a WebAPI 2 webservice.  I have already done some of the simple methods that we have that just take simpel input parameters...

```
public int HelloWorld(int parm){
   if(parm == 3){ return "you are stupid";}
   else if (parm == 2) { return "No you are stupid"; }
   else { return "In any event, Hello World!"}
}
```

But I have several cases where I need to pass in large complex types into the methods.

```
public IEnumerable<ComplexObjects> processComplexObjs(ComplexObjects firstParm, ComplexObjects secondParm){
   ...
   return List<ComplexObjects>;
}
```

Apparently you can't have more than one complex object if you use [FromBody] as an attribute peppered around the parameter.  Apparently there is a way you can JSONObject to do this.  Are there any good examples of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

this gives one way around it

http://blog.travisgosselin.com/web-api-signatures-with-multiple-complex-parameters/

Basically, use the JObject to store the complex classes.